# Facing problem once i change the url parameter in Mongodb Driver - Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a model called `Product`:

```
class Product {
    constructor(title, price, description, imageUrl) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    
    save() {
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection("products").insertOne(this)
        .catch(error => dbDebugger(error));
    }
    
    static fetchById(productId) {
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection("products").findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(productId) })
        .catch(error => dbDebugger(error.message));
    }

}
```

and in one of my controllers i tried to find the product with the `productId` which will come from the url as a url parameter:

```
exports.getSingleProduct = (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    
    Product.fetchById(productId)
    .then(product => {
        if(!product) {
            return res.redirect("404");
        }
        res.render("product-detail", { product, pageTitle: "Product Detail" });
    })
    .catch(error => dbDebugger(error));
};
```

and indeed everything work without no issue.
but once i change the `productId` from url(like appending one letter to it), i'll see an error (even though i should be able to handle it in my controller).

```
BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

I think the error is coming from my model once i tried to convert it to `ObjectId`, if it is how can i fix that? and if its not then where that error is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs before any async code starts and `.catch()` is only used for handling rejected promises.

I would recommend using `async` functions instead which will treat synchronous and asynchronous failures the same way

```js
static async fetchById(productId) {
  const db = getDb();
  try {
    return await db.collection("products")
      .findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(productId) });
  } catch (error) {
    dbDebugger(error.message);
    throw error; // don't forget to keep the promise rejection going
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you're trying to cast a none valid value into the `ObjectId`, I am not familiar with `mongoose` `fetchById`, I'm assuming it's a custom function you or your team wrote where you cast the `_id` into `ObjectId`,

My guess the code looks a little like this:

```
fetchById(id){
  return this.model.findOne({_id: new ObjectId(id)})
}
```

This is why when you manually corrupt the objectid string it becomes a none valid objectid, and when the casting happens it throws an error. I would personally recommend adding validation to the REST route to make sure the `param.id` is actually a valid `ObjectId`.

Comment: No need to guess, the code is in the question (line #17 of the first code block)

Comment: Ah :), I guessed right then.